# Creating an auto logout timer of 30 minutes in PHP

Tags: php

I need a timer of 30 min to auto logout my quiz application coded in PHP. It should be a forced one. Even if the user is doing some activities.How to implement that?

Comment: This is impossible by means of php only, since php runs on the server side and the server does not have access to the client, expect when the client chooses to contact the server.

Comment: Maybe same topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516969/automatic-logout-after-15-minutes-of-inactive-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php ajax auto logout with timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801935/php-ajax-auto-logout-with-timer)

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119451/page-redirect-after-certain-time-php

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not work like a runtime application, it doesn't have a state. Your frontend via javascript or other means would need to send a request to the server on an interval to check if the user is still authenticated. Then you check using PHP if the user is expired or not, in which case you action that using the frontend logic.

This is way too vague to give a definitive answer.